# How to intepret the vector space of nxn Matrices over $\mathbb{R}$(real numbers) as an $ \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}} $vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $ V=\mathbb{R}^{nxn} $ be the vector space of nxn-Matrices, in an exercise I need to interpret V as $ \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}} $.

Can somebody explain me, how this is possible?

PS: I'm not used to write about math in english, please ask if something doesn't makes sense to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question makes perfectly sense. Note that each $n\times n$ matrix has $n^2$ entries. So, for instance, it is natural to identify the set of all $3\times3$ matrices with $\mathbb{R}^{3^2}(=\mathbb{R}^9)$, like this:$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}\mapsto(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i),$$for instance.